# How to configure JVM Argument -javaagent with two jars

Tags: java, aop, javaagents

To use the spring AOP, I have to configure **-javaagent:C:/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar** as JVM argument. But there is a jar that is already configured i.e. **-javaagent:C:/other.jar**

Now how can I configure both jars with -javaagent so that both jars should work properly?

Also there may be the different approaches to configure multiple jars with -javaagent in Windows and Linux environment. Please suggest the solution for both of the environments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One java application may have any number of agents by using -javaagent: option any number of times. Agents are invoked in the same order as specified in options

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the idea.